# How to implement angular circular slider in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hello i stumble upon this codepen [link](https://codepen.io/ajp8164/pen/XXBQaj) that uses a circular slider in ionic. I added the component to my project by npm `(https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-circular-slider)` but i don't know how to actually implement this in an ionic app. Forgive me i'm still a newbie in angular and ionic. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you can try the https://roundsliderui.com/ plugin, which can be used in angular 2+ projects also. So I hope you can use this in the ionic 4. Check the below sample for the usage in angular7: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-round-slider

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing angular and angularjs. Angular2 and the following versions are not compatible to angularjs. Since you're using Ionic4, which is also using the new angular, you have to look for another package. Most packages on npm for angular2 and higher are using keywords like ngx, ng or simply angular.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support Ionic 4, as iconic running Angular 2 instead of Angulerjs.